# Woocommerce emails: send text only to customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added some text to the Woocommerce-order-processing-email with this:

```
add_action(
    'woocommerce_email_before_order_table',    
    'add_order_email_instructions', 
    0
);

function add_order_email_instructions( $order ) {
    if ( 'paypal' == $order->payment_method ) {
        echo 'my text:';
    } 
}
```

and this works, but I would like the text to be only in the email that is sent to the customer, NOT the admin. What would I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in two args.

```
add_action(
    'woocommerce_email_before_order_table',    
    'add_order_email_instructions', 
    0,2
);
```

The second arg is the conditional you want.

```
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
    if ( 'paypal' == $order->payment_method && !$sent_to_admin) {
        echo 'my text:';
    } 
}
```

Limit action to when order is processing:

```
  add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'scriptonomy_when_processing');
    function scriptonomy_when_processing(){  
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 0,2); 
}
```

Comment: Great, and how can I edit it to hve it only displayed in the order-processing email? (Not the order completed, invoice etc)

Comment: Hook into the woocommerce_order_status_processing action

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner, would you mind telling me how?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the code sample.